# How many ways to put 60 balls into 10 boxes such that each box has at least one ball and all boxes contain a different number of balls?

Tags: combinatorics

Put 60 identical balls into 10 identical boxes such that each box has at least one ball while all boxes contain a different number of balls. How many ways can you do so?

Answer (score 1):

Write the $10$ counts per box in increasing order and compute the pairwise differences, which must exceed $0$. The total is the sum of the terms of the prefix sum of the differences, plus one.

Let us start with the differences $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\to1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\to55$. So we have a budget of $5$ to fill. Now if we increment the $k^{\text{th}}$ difference, the total increases by $10-k$.

Hence, the number of possibilities is the number of partitions of the number $5$. There are $\color{green}7$ such partitions.

E.g. $5=2+2+1\to1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2\to1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11,13\to60.$

More generally, for a total of $n$, take then number of partitions of $n-55$, excluding those with a component that exceeds $9$.

E.g. for the total $70$, there are $176$ partitions of $15$, but $19$ of them have a term above $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's place the $10$ boxes in a row. Without loss of generality, we assume that after we are done placing the balls in the boxes, the number of balls in a box will increase as we move from left to right.

Now, the first step is to make sure that each box has at least one ball and no two boxes have the same number of balls. So, we place $1$ ball in the first ball, $2$ balls in the second ball, $3$ balls in the third, and so on. In other words, $i$ balls in the $i^{\text{th}}$ box. That means we have placed $55$ balls and have $5$ balls remaining.

So now our task is reduced to placing the $5$ remaining boxes such that no two boxes end up with the same number of balls. It's obvious that for every ball we place in a box, we must place at least $1$ ball in each of the boxes on the right. Or else, the condition of increasing towards right will be violated.

So, it's clear we can't place any balls in the first $5$ boxes. Here are the different ways in which we can place the $5$ balls in the last five boxes (labeled $B_6 - B_{10}$).

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
B_6 &B_7 &B_8 &B_9 &B_{10} \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 &0 &5 \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 &1 &4 \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 &2 &3 \\ \hline
0 &0 &1 &1 &3 \\ \hline
0 &0 &1 &2 &2 \\ \hline
0 &1 &1 &1 &2 \\ \hline
1 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\ 
\end{array}

So yeah, this gives us the only $7$ ways to place $60$ identical balls into $10$ identical boxes such that each box has at least one ball while all boxes contain a different number of balls.

Please feel free to correct me, if there are any errors.

Comment: Your findings are correct.